# Netty 4 IpFilter

Tags: netty

I'm going through the new Netty code organization and it seems that the handler package (see https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/handler/src/main/java/io/netty/handler) has gone through a diet.

Where did the `ipfilter` package go? I couldn't read anything about it in the news (http://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-4.x.html).

My guess is that the ChannelHandler refactoring along with the new auto-read flag (as described in [Sensible and less error-prone inbound traffic suspension](http://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-4.x.html#wiki-h3-20)) makes the ipfilter package obsolete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm I think it is still useful. Could you please open a request in our bug-tracker. We will port it over then. Or even better do a PR maybe ? ;)